# Java Persistence - can not read time from the oracle table column

Tags: java, jpa, timestamp

I am using persistence and hql to read a date from an oracle DB into java code. However, the values for hours, minutes and seconds are always set to 00

Here is my code :

```
...
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HotelskoResenjeWSPersistence");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // what i read from the db is stored here :
        List<PpaDrCdr> resultSet = null;

        String queryString = "select "
                +"id, to_timestamp(substr(chargestart, 1, 17), 'dd.mm.rr hh24:mi:ss') as chargestart "
                +"from myoracle@database t "
                +"where t.answertime is not null "
                +"and t.reportedduration > 0 "
                +"and t.directorynumber = :mdn "
                +"order by servicestart";

        try{
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString, PpaDrCdr.class);

            resultSet = query
                    .setParameter("mdn", account.getMdn())
                    .getResultList();

        }catch(HibernateException ex){
            // processing exception here
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if(resultSet != null && !resultSet.isEmpty()){
            for ( PpaDrCdr row : resultSet ) {
                System.out.println("\n\t"+
                            new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(row.getDate1())+
                            "\n");
            }
        }
        ...
```

This always prints out the time to be 00:00:00 for each and every date read from the database, which is totally wrong.
My jpa class is a simple one :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ppa_dr_cdr")
    public class PpaDrCdr {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="chargestart")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date chargestart;

        public Date getChargestart() {
        return chargestart;
        }
        public void setChargestart(Date chargestart) {
            this.chargestart = chargestart;
        }
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
...
```

Why doesn't persistence read the time ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that have full date with time in database? Also your're using native SQL query, not HQL.

Comment: Why on earth would you hardcode HibernateException when using the JPA API?! JPA API guarantees JPA exceptions and then your code is portable ... well, it isnt datastore portable due to your use of hacky SQL, but thats a different story

Answer (score 0):

Use java.time.LocalDateTime

```
    @Column(name="chargestart")
    @Basic
    private LocalDateTime chargestart;
```

It's already a known Basic Datatype in Hibernate.
(-> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic )

Also, I'd suggest using Hibernate's Criteria API for querying. Avoiding SQL statements is one of the benefits of using Hibernate.

Comment: I have to use the query because the table has 23 columns and i need just the specific values. Still, I will go through the tutorial you posted. Maybe i will think of something.

Comment: The problem is that each timestamp read from the databsae is reset to midnight (00:00:00) somewhere between my query and the setting of my class variable and i have no idea why.

Comment: The @Basic annotation is optional as LocalDateTime is already known to Hibernate.

Comment: The Date being reset sounds weird. I guess that this has to do with the mapping between SQL types in the database and Java types. My coworkers told me that java.util.Date as well as java.sql.Date should never be used as they often cause problems regarding database-type-conversion. That's why we use LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally solved it. I ditched the entity class, loaded everything from the database as a `List<Object[]>` for a result set, and then casted individual objects into what i needed :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistence");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

List<Object[]> oList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

try{
    Session s1 = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    oList = s1.getNamedQuery("MyNamedQueryFromOrmXml")
                    .setParameter("mdn", account.getMdn())
                    .list();
}catch(HibernateException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    ApplicationContext context = 
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:beans.xml");
    GenericFaultType gft = ((HibernateExceptionToGFTConverter)context.getBean("GFTbean")).convert(ex);

    throw new GetCDREntryListFaultMsg("HibernateException occurred", gft, ex);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

// this is what i will need :
List<CDREntry> cdrE = new ArrayList<CDREntry>();
for(Object[] o : oList){
    if(o!=null){
        try{
            CDREntry pom = new CDREntry();

            pom.setId((long)o[0]);
            // AND NOW I GET TIME TOO !!!
            pom.setChargingStart((Timestamp)o[1]);
            //...
            cdrE.add(pom);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("\n\tFailed to cast "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

No idea why the old one didn't work, but here is how it works now, with session and orm.xml